# Magento: hreflang meta tag with multistore setup

Tags: magento, seo

We have a multistore setup in Magento - well, a two-store setup:

- English for USD transactions and,
- English for CAD transactions

The "en" store goes with the default URL — i.e. domain.com/
The "en-ca" store is setup as a subfolder — i.e.  domain.com/ca/

The product/category URLs are all the same, they're merely appended at the end of the above store URLs.

We need to add the following tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://domain.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="http://domain.com/ca/" />
```

where the product/category urls are appended to the store domains in the href tag.

For a Product URL:    domain.com/product-name.html   the above tags should become:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://domain.com/product-name.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="http://domain.com/ca/product-name.html" />
```

For a Category url:    domain.com/category1/subcategory2/  the above tags should become:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://domain.com/category1/subcategory2/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-ca" href="http://domain.com/ca/category1/subcategory2/" />
```

What needs to be added to the template header .phtml files in order to get these output correctly for each product or category page, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your header file:

```
<?php $url = str_replace(".com",".com/ca" , Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); ?>
<link href="<?php echo $url; ?>" hreflang="en-CA" rel="alternate" />

<?php $url = str_replace(".com/ca",".com" , Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); ?>
<link href="<?php echo $url; ?>" hreflang="en" rel="alternate" />
```

It will generate the hreflang URL for you.

Comment: Thank you this appears to work great; however, there is a slight problem for us. We use a Geo/IP module that directs Canadian users (based on their IP address location) straight to the "domain.com/ca" domain while all others are taken to "domain.com". With the above code, what happens for the "en-CA" href link is that we get "domain.com/ca/ca/..." on all href urls — note the double /ca/ca/ which makes the tags point to non-existent urls. Is there a way to overcome the double /ca/ca/ in this situation?